# xpath selection of a title node within a resultset

Tags: ruby, xpath, xhtml, xpath-2.0

I've an xml doc like below. I was trying to select a title node with a particular value in it say `"![CDATA[ 1234 ]]"`. That `Title` node may be in any `Type` node. I was using this xpath query

```
/Results/ResultSet/Type[Title="![CDATA[ 1234 ]]"]
```

but didnt get anything selected. can someone pls help.

```
<Results>
    <Info>...</Info>
    <ResultSet num="4">

     <Type type="A">

      <Title>
      <![CDATA[ 1234 ]]>
      </Title>

      <Description>
      <![CDATA[ 1234 ]]>
      </Description>

      <Domain>
      <![CDATA[1234 ]]>
      </Domain>

      <Target>
      <![CDATA[]]>
      </Target>

     </Type>

    <Type type="A">

    <Title>
    <![CDATA[ abcdef ]]>
    </Title>

    <Description>
    <![CDATA[abcdef]]>
    </Description>

    <Domain>
    <![CDATA[abcdef]]>
    </Domain>

    <Target>
    <![CDATA[abcdef]]>
    </Target>

    </Type>
```

EDIT: included the ruby code that I am using

```
       doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
       Element = doc.xpath('/Results/ResultSet/Type/Title[text()=" 1234 "]')
    if Element.empty?()
          puts "not there "
    else
       Element.each do |node|
       puts  "Found Title: #{node.text}" 
       end
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath is wrong:

Use this:

```
/Results/ResultSet/Type/Title[text()=" 1234 "]
```

Based on the link OP posted for the XML, here is the working XPath:

```
/QuigoResults/ResultSet/Listing/Title[text()=" location in DYNAMICREGION "]
```

Comment: To explain it, `CDATA` is a short for `character data` and is a XML tag to indicate to the parser to ignore the data inside, not to parse them. It's useful e.g. when storing tags/documents in a XML document, because `<`, `>` and `&` are illegal characters in XML and you couldn't store them, otherwise..

Comment: @Chandu I tried the above query , but its not selecting the node. The nodeset that it is returning is empty.  Is it because of the CDATA stuff that it has in there? or something else is going on

Comment: I tested the XPATH against the given Xml. Are you sure the structure of XML is same as what you have posted?

Comment: @Chandu Heres the link to the whole xml doc [xml link](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1Iu5YB-CYKDOo-eigloj3bhjvlviedxcDLJ5gSQv9YzU) . I also included the code above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1207289 Updated the post with the XPath matchien your XML. Also check this saved version as a reference http://www.xpathtester.com/saved/8d788546-ac89-4085-a50b-012159024db1

Comment: @Chandu ok , got it working. The issue was spaces between `"` and the text `1234`. It now prints the title. Thanks a lot!